# What does it mean the interpreter directly executes code?

Tags: python, interpreter, execution

I have read this statement that the interpreter *directly* executes the code. But I am not sure I understand what it means. I have been trying to get a good article on the execution cycle of python code.

I understand that the python code is converted to byte code and fed to the interpreter. So what happens next? Can someone explain clearly the steps that goes into it, especially in relation between the byte code, interpreter, OS and CPU?

Something along the lines of...

1. OS loads the python interpreter in main memory
2. CPU fetches the instruction and performs ALU. Updates the memory.. etc

**Edited for clarity:** My basic confusion is if CPU is what is executing the code, then what is meaning of saying 'the interpreter executes the code'?

Comment: You should link to where you read this. Seems dodgy to me, and very much dependent on what the author meant by "directly".

Comment: I suspect that the author of that quote was trying to say how the interpreter usually takes one line of code at a time rather than being fed a full script.

Comment: Well, this is where I saw it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode

Comment: and here as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is a massive hand-waving over the whole process. Here's how it goes, try to keep up:

1. Python code is [lexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) into an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST).
2. The AST is [translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translator_%28computing%29) into Python [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).
3. The Python bytecode is loaded into the Python [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual_machines).
4. The Python virtual machine reads the bytecode and calls out to native functions as the bytecode requires/specifies.

The CPU never sees the bytecode as anything but data, and it does not need to see it any other way.

Comment: *...try to keep up*--lol.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the python VM reads the bytecode. My question is what is the difference/relation between the execution by an interpreter and the execution by CPU?

Comment: @user567: Exactly what point 4 and the end note specify. In short, *absolutely no correlation whatsoever*.

Comment: I also found this extremely helpful: http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/04/02/pythons-innards-introduction/

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  if VM take care of executing the byte code dose that mean there is no machine code conversion and VM dose not send it to CPU for execution ? Is CPU idle in this case

Answer (score 0):

To directly execute the code would imply that the interpreter does not represent the interpreted program as machine code, then allow the actual machine to execute it.  Instead, the interpreter carries out the instructions (with or without conversion to some kind of bytecode) itself.

Technically, the machine carries out the interpreter's code, but the fact remains that no new machine code is ever generated.

The contrasting approaches are statically compiled code (translation into machine code, no further interpretation is necessary) and JIT (optional translation into bytecode, translate bytecode or textual program into machine code at runtime, allow machine to execute).

Comment: Thanks. You have mentioned that the interpreter carries out the instruction... now what does that mean? Is it not the CPU which carries out the instruction? what is the relation between the two?